# React : use onItemTouchTap to change backgroundcolor

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use MenuItem of material ui. So I have :

```
<Paper style={style.paper}>
    <Menu onItemTouchTap={onItemTouchTapCb}>

            <MenuItem primaryText="Accès rapides" leftIcon={<RemoveRedEye />} style={style.menuTitle}  />
            <MenuItem primaryText="Tous les documents" />
            <MenuItem primaryText="Mes documents" />
            <Divider />
            <MenuItem primaryText="Nouveaux" />
            <MenuItem primaryText="Documents à observer" />

    </Menu>
</Paper>
```

I call the callback onItemTouchTapCb to change the background color of an item when I click it on. However, I don't know how to implement this function :

```
function onItemTouchTapCb() {
    console.log("ok")
}
```

Do you have an idea ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just like this :

```
<Paper style={style.paper}>
<Menu 
   onItemTouchTap={this.onItemTouchTapCb}>
</Menu>
```

Be careful, if you need to invoke the context, your function will have to look like this :

```
onItemTouchTapCb = () => {
   console.log("ok")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I agree with you, for the form of function, but my problem is how to change the background color of item when I click on this ? Can I call css property ?

Comment: Yes, a css property would work fine. You could re-render the component with a different className, if you have to modify multiple CSS properties

Answer (score 0):

If you're using local state you could use something like this to toggle between two colors. In your constructor(assuming you're using es6 class):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        backgroundColor: true
    };
}
```

And your style object:

```
style = {
    paper: {
       backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor ? 'red' : 'blue'
    }
}
```

And your function:

```
onItemTouchTapCb = () => {
   this.setState({backgroundColor: !this.state.backgroundColor})
}
```

Paper:

```
<Paper style={style.paper}>
    <Menu 
       onItemTouchTap={this.onItemTouchTapCb}>
    </Menu>
</Paper>
```

If you need to manipulate more than one CSS property or have the background change between more than two colors use a className as Victor says in his answer. You could use the same logic with local state to change the className if you want.